# Is polemic a naturally disengenious, flawed argumentation?

Tags: meaning, expressions

I wanted to ask about the meaning of the word polemic the way it is colloquially used. The dictionary definition is:
"a strong verbal or written attack on someone or something."

But I was always under an impression that a polemic also carried the notion that the argumentation was disingenuous and flawed. And certainly carried a negative connotation. Is that true?

Comment: Polemic is not argumentation. Polemic is avoiding argumentation by rhetoric and appeals to emotion.

Comment: No, a polemic need not be disingenuous and flawed.  For example, in the run-up to the Civil War in the US there were many polemics against slavery that were published.  More recently, we have seen polemics against the use of fossil fuels.  See famous polemicists listed here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polemic